# Hibernate transforming returned data objects into wrapper class

Tags: java, hibernate

I’m currently working on my first hibernate project an ran into some design issues.
Since I didn’t want any business logic in my DataObjects returned from Hibernate and didn’t want to use the business logic manager for every setter/getter, I decided to create a wrapper class that encapsulates these objects.
When using criteria/hibernate queries I created a `ResultTransformer` that will transform the hibernate DataObject into a wrapper class. So now all objects returned by any query method are “wrapper” classes instead of the DO’s.

But now I also want to use the same logic for children of My objects. Take for example the following object:

```
public class BookDO{

     @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     protected List<ChapterDO> chapters;

     public ChapterDO getChapters(){ return chapters;}
}
```

The getChapters method (which will be called by my book manager) will return me instances of the ChapterDO object but what I want to return is instances of the “wrapped” Chapter class.
One additional concern is that when I want to add a chapter :

```
public class BookDO{
    public void addChapter(ChapterDO chapter)
    {
        chapters.add(chapter)
    }
}
public class BookManager()
{
     public void addChapter(Chapter chapter)
     {
          bookDOObject.add(chapter);
     }
}
```

But this will fail since the book manager only has access to the wrapper object, so I would have to “unwrap” it. I’m hesitant to just add a getChapterDo() method to the wrapper since I feel this would be a “hack".

So I was wondering what the best way to deal with this sort of situation is ? Do I need to create `unwrappers/wrappers` on the manager level or is there something in hibernate that will allow me to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using wrappers, 
yes you would need "unwrap" by mapping wrapper's state to entity just before committing to database.